# Slim-Lang: render container conditionally

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, slim-lang

I am working with Slim to render some elements with [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), I'm trying to render pairs of columns inside a row container, as follows:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    Container 1 - Left
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    Container 2 - Right
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    Container 3 - Left
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    Container 4 - Right
  </div>
</div>
```

The objective is to render these columns correctly regardless of the height of them.

The slim code that I am trying to use is the following:

```
- [1,2,3,4].each_with_index do |num, index|
  .row # I want this row to appear only on odd iterations
    .col-xs-6 Container #{num} - #{index % 2 == 0 ? "Left" : "Right"}
```

Is there an elegant way to do it?

I've thought of:

- Having a single row and after 2 columns, add a page break of a `.col-xs-12` column.
- Getting the n and n+1 items and render them on a single loop.

The question goes:

Is there a way to render the container once and then add a child on a later iteration?

Comment: when using bootstrap i think you can add all of the elements to one row and it will adjust auto

Comment: It happens when you add several columns, but one of them is taller than the rest the flow gets obstructed.

Comment: have you looked at responsive column resets http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets

Comment: Do you have you anything against a nested loop? With parent loop you would generate rows and with nested loop you would place desired number of columns in each of your rows

Comment: I like the loops to be as simple as possible, if I take the nest loop approach I should have to make the first loop the deliver pairs of elements and the nested to iterate over those pairs.